# Untab in nano: move a block of code to the left

Tags: linux, nano

How can I "Untab", move a block of code to the left in nano?

In most gui editors shift+tab works but can't find anything for nano.

Comment: The answer is use vim =)

Answer (score 5):

With an english keyboard-layout `Ctrl + Alt + {` should work to unindent tabs (*untab*) in Nano Text Editor.

If you use a keyboard-layout which needs `Alt-Gr` for curly braces, use `ESC` then `{` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Manjaro,Year: 2022>> give "shift+tab" a try after you have mark"alt+a" your selected texts.